# Can't seem to get this "if-statement" right. Vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, if-statement, proxy, split

Basically I am splitting up a random line from a text box into 4 parts: a proxy, the proxy ip, and if the user has supplied a username and password those become parts 3 and 4.

I don't want the proxy credentials to be used if the user has not supplied them, and has only supplied the proxy ip and port.  Here is my code:

```
If SwitchButton2.Value = True Then
                            randomline = RandomNumbers.Next(proxybox.Lines.Length)
                            Dim s As String = proxybox.Lines(randomline)
                            RandomProxy = Split(s, ":", , CompareMethod.Text)
                            request.Proxy = New WebProxy(RandomProxy(0).ToString & ":" & RandomProxy(1).ToString)

                            Try
                                If RandomProxy(2) And RandomProxy(3) IsNot Nothing Then
                                    request.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                                    request.Proxy.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(RandomProxy(2).ToString, RandomProxy(3).ToString)
                                End If

                            Catch
                                MessageBox.Show("no credentials")
                            End Try
                        End If
```

I am having trouble with the If statment here:

```
Try
                            If RandomProxy(2) And RandomProxy(3) IsNot Nothing Then
                                request.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                                request.Proxy.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(RandomProxy(2).ToString, RandomProxy(3).ToString)
                            End If

                        Catch
                            MessageBox.Show("no credentials")
                        End Try
```

I am getting the exception thrown everytime, what am i doing wrong with it?  I only want the proxy credentials to be used if they are supplied and continue on if not.

Comment: Please don’t write `= True` in an `If` statement, it’s pointless.

Comment: I am using a dotnetbar component and it has a value of true or false.  not sure what you mean?

Comment: `If something = True` is the same as `If something = True = True` is the same as `If something = True = True = True` is the same as `If something`. Use `If something`.

Comment: Ah ok.  It's redundant I see what your saying, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test each of the values separately:

```
If RandomProxy(2) IsNot Nothing AndAlso RandomProxy(3) IsNot Nothing Then
```

You should also test to see if enough elements exist in the array prior to attempting to use them:

```
If RandomProxy IsNot Nothing 
AndAlso RandomProxy.Length >= 4
AndAlso RandomProxy(2) IsNot Nothing 
AndAlso RandomProxy(3) IsNot Nothing Then
```

and finally

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  I will try this out, defiently makes sense.